# Applying a transducer directly and with "transduce" yield different results

Tags: clojure, transducer

As far as I understand, a transducer is a function that transforms a reducer function before `reduce` takes place. In other words, `(transduce transducer reducer collection)` is equivalent to `(reduce (transducer reducer) collection)`. So these two expressions

```
(reduce ((map inc) -) 0 [3 4 5])
(transduce (map inc) - 0 [3 4 5])
```

must return the same value. Right?

Wrong

```
(reduce ((map inc) -) 0 [3 4 5])    -15
(transduce (map inc) - 0 [3 4 5])    15
```

A bug or a feature? My version of Clojure is `1.8.0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that `(transduce)` implements a slightly different algorithm.

`(reduce)` calls `(reducer aggregate element)` for every element in the collection. A total of `n` calls for a collection of `n` elements.

`(transduce)` calls `(reducer aggregate element)` for every element and then for some reason calls `(reducer aggregate)` again, making `n+1` calls. As a result, `(transduce)` doesn't work as expected with `(-)`.

Comment: by the way, this is what `completing` is for - if you use `transduce` with `(completing -)` instead of `-`, you will get your expected result